# How do I find commit messages that contain certain words?

Tags: git, grep

I want to search commits in my repository and find ones that contain 2 specific words in their commit messages (say, wordA AND wordB). How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the words must go together, just put them between "

```
git log --grep "wordA wordB"
```

If they are not together but the order is always the same you can do this with a regex:

```
git log --grep "wordA.*wordB"
```

Comment: It is not working because this words are not written in the commit message after each other. There can be many words between them.

Comment: It they always in the same order you can try the second option. It should work

Comment: This is among the reasons knowing regex should be in any developers' toolbox.